# What does false !== in a conditional statement with assignment cause?

Tags: php, compare, expression

This seems to be a special case in some programming languages. In the php manual, I cannot find the meaning.

```
(false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
```

There is an 'assignment on the right, comparison on the left, but what does the whole operator mean?

Does using this have any special considerations?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean != ? I'm not really up to date with PHP, but I've never heard of a !== operator.

Comment: You'll want to read up on the [comparison operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
```

means that

- $file is assigned with value readdir($handle)
- and then checks if the value isn't **EXACTLY** "**NOT** false"

if the $file = readdir($handle) returns the value NULL, and you have this code:

```
if (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
//do something
}
```

"Do something" would be executed, because NULL is not false.

If $file returns 0 - "Do something" would be executed because 0 is not false.

If $file returns the value false, "Do something" would not be executed.

If you instead have this code: (one less = operator)

```
if (false != ($file = readdir($handle))) {
//do something
}
```

the meaning is:

- $file is assigned with value readdir($handle)
- and then checks if the evaluation of the value is "**NOT** false"

"Do something" would not be executed, because NULL is evaluated to false.

If $file returns 0 - "Do something" would not be executed because 0 is evaluated to false.

If $file returns the value false, "Do something" would not be executed.

Above is just for trying to describe how the !== operator works. readdir()-function does not return all of these values (null, 0, false).

Comment: This answer is what the question was asking. Can you fix the spelling of exactly in the 1st list?

Comment: @David, I did my best to answer it! Thanks for noticing the spelling. I've fixed it now! :-)

Comment: readdir() can return 0, for eg, if the file name it is reading is zero

Answer (score 2):

This is shorthand for the following:

```
$file = readdir($handle);
if (false !== $file) {
// etc
}
```

This would most commonly be found as the conditional of a while loop.  There are two things to note:

1. They are using strict checking (!== instead of !=) because readdir can return things that are "falsey", like empty strings.
2. This is incredibly opaque syntax and I would shoot any of my juniors who brought this to me.

**EDIT** In response to OP's questions:

PHP has both "loose" and "strict" value checking.  Loose checking uses the == and != operators, and it compares "truthy" versus "falsey" values. False, 0 or empty stings or arrays are all "falsey", so the condition ("" == false) evaluates to true, as does (0 == Array()).

Strict checking uses the === and !==.  This means that the tested variables must be *identical*, so (0 === false) evaluates to false, while (0 === 0) evaluates to true.

For an explanation of what this means for the readdir function, the [manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php) has a big red box on it explaining it.

Comment: Great comment #2. You're saying that because the right side 'could' return something non-boolean, this further 'tests' the result. ?? `if (#2) how would you improve the syntax?

Comment: +1 for comment#2! :-)

Comment: @Matt, The reason why that code makes sense is when used in `while` clause, not when used in `if` clause. Even php.net entry supports it.

Comment: @Raidenance I agree that assignments within conditionals have a use case.  However, I think that this is one of those things that, like ternary operators, increment/decrement operators or braceless syntax makes the code opaque and hard to maintain.  It is better to add a couple of lines of code to make it clearer.  Ultimately, though, this is a question of taste and I respect your point.

Answer (score 1):

It's not particularly a special case.

PHP tries to execute the readdir() function and assign the result to the $file variable. If readdir() succeeds, then $file will contain the directory values; but if it fails it will contain a Boolean false. So PHP executes the readdir() and tests if the result is false or not... the false as the left value in the comparison test is simply a stylistic feature.

Often you'll see

```
if (false == $x)
```

rather than

```
if ($x == false)
```

when doing a comparison.
They both do exactly the same thing, except that

```
if (false = $x)
```

will throw a notice (if error logging is enabled) if you mistype the comparison operator, whereas

```
if ($x = false)
```

won't show any notice, and will assign a value of false to $x which probably wasn't intended and can introduce problems and bugs in the code

Comment: Thanks Mark. Is the meaning the same removing the `false !==` ?? Isn't this a double-test?

Comment: @David, it is a redundancy in this case, and should really be rewritten as two lines (as others have said) with a view to readability

Answer (score 1):

Decomposed:

```
$file = readdir($handle);

if ($file !== false) {

}
```

Quoting from the PHP manual on `readdir`:

> This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a
>   non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on
>   Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the
>   return value of this function.

Answer (score 1):

That's basically two statements in one:

```
$file = readdir($handle);
if($file !== false) 
{
  //do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`readdir()` gives either FALSE **OR** the name of the next item in the current dir it is reading.

Supposing the directory is readable, $file will have the name of the next file or dir.

So `(false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))` becomes:

```
(false !== <name_of_a_file_or_dir>) //dir was read and the name passed to $file
```

In this case the comparison will resolve to TRUE.

Supposing the directory is not readable, $file will become FALSE.
So `(false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))` becomes:

```
(false !== false) //because dir was not readable
```

In this case the comparison will resolve to FALSE.